# get A members from set<A*,Comparator> to list<A>

Tags: c++, list, stl, set

I have a set of `A*` pointers pointing to objects allocated on the heap sorted with a comparator (using the `operator()` in a `struct PtrComparator` ) like this: `set<A*,PtrComparator>`

The comparator sorts it according to `A.m_timeStamp.timeStamp` which is a `basic_string`.
However I am *forced to* extract a `list<A>` using a range described by two string parameters and return it to the caller.
So I need to use those two parameters to get a range of iterators I guess? And then fill the list?

How do I do this?

I am afraid that any temporary `A` object I create will be destroyed when the function terminates so how do I even store it in the `list<A>`? Am I not forced to use the heap again?

I am not allowed to change the `list<A>` to `list<A*>` but I can modify my implementation to suite the `list<A>` return type, however how do I get around the problem with temporary objects when trying to fill the set somewhere in a constructor. Could I have an implemantation with a `set<A>`?

```
struct PtrComparator;
class A
 {
   public:
                   A           ( const CTimeStamp & timeStamp,
                                 const string     & from,
                                   const ABody  & body,
                                 const Attach    * attach );
    A(const A&);
    ~A();
    const string     & From      ( void ) const;
    const ABody  & Body         ( void ) const;
    const CTimeStamp & TimeStamp  ( void ) const;
    const Attach* Attachment     ( void ) const;
    // will do the above getters later
    friend ostream & operator <<   ( ostream & os, const A & x );
    //friend bool operator< (const A&,const A&);
    friend struct PtrComparator;

   private:
    CTimeStamp m_timeStamp;
    string m_from;
    ABody m_body;
    const Attach * m_ptr_to_attach;
 };
    //normal constructor
 A::A(const CTimeStamp & timeStamp,const string & from,
      const ABody & body,const Attach * attach)
 :m_timeStamp(timeStamp),m_from(from),m_body(body),m_ptr_to_attach(attach)//,count_(0)
 {
    attach->AddRef();
 }
 //copy constructor
{
//similar to normal constructor
}

//destructor
A::~A()
{
    m_ptr_to_attach->Release();
}
 ostream & operator<< (ostream & os,const A & x) 
 {
     os << "body:" <<x.m_body <<" , from: " << x.m_from << " , attachment: " 
     <<  (x.m_ptr_to_attach) <<" , timestamp:" << x.m_timeStamp;

     return os;
 }

struct PtrComparator{
 bool operator()(const A* first,const A* second)
 {
     return first->m_timeStamp.timestamp < second->m_timeStamp.timestamp;
 }
};
class Box_of_A
 {
   public:
                   Box_of_A ();
                   ~Box_of_A();
    bool           Delivery       ( const A      & a );
    bool           NewFolder     ( const string     &  folderName );

    **list<A>    ListOfA      ( const string     & folderName,
                               const CTimeStamp & from,
                               const CTimeStamp & to );**
    typedef map<string,set<A*,PtrComparator> * >::const_iterator  folders_c_it;
    typedef map<string,set<A*,PtrComparator> * >::iterator  folders_it;
   private:

    map<string,set<A*,PtrComparator> * > folders;
 };

bool Box_of_A::Delivery(const A & a)
{
    folders_it it = folders.find("index");
    if(it == folders.end())return false;
    set<A*,PtrComparator>* & folder = it->second;
    A * newA = new A(a);
    folder->insert(newA);

    return true;
}
```

I am missing the function

```
list<A>    ListOfA      ( const string     & folderName,
                            const CTimeStamp & from,
                             const CTimeStamp & to );
```

CTimeStamp has a member `basic_string timeStamp`.

Could somebody show me a way out of this mess?

Comment: [std::copy()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)

Comment: I thought I could not use std::copy() because I have `A*` in the set and I need `A` in the list, isnt that the case? If not , could you provide me with example code?

Comment: Oh, use std::transform() in that case. The transformation is just dereferencing the pointer

Comment: Too long explanation without any code. Currently, it is more difficult to understand it than it would be with some demonstrating code. What does this even mean? `However I am forced to extract a list<A> using a range described by two string parameters and return it to the caller.`

Comment: Could you provide me with the transformation code please? I do not know how to write it. :)

Comment: OK, I will add some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
map<string,set<A*,PtrComparator> * > folders
```

to this:

```
map<string,set<A,Comparator> > folders
```

and magically your life will become better.

Comment: This was for a school assignment. For some reason I thought `std: set` and `map` would not store the temporary object (that is being "added" to them). I started implementing everything on the heap manually. Thats why the crazy pointers are there. All the things they were teaching us about deep copies and temporary objects got me overly paranoid. :D

Comment: on a modern processor copies are usually extremely cheap when compared to the cost of a cache miss,which is more likely with pointers.